# Is Cassandra mostly immune to the Compressed OOPS problem?

Tags: java, pointers, cassandra

I'm reading about the [Java Compressed OOPS](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/). I see that what Java does is a lot of shifting to use *compressed* pointers for all their object references.

What I can understand is that with a large number of objects, going from `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` to `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`, you may end up using a *lot more* memory.

Say you have 1 million objects, in the first case, you need 4Mb of data for references, in the second case, you need 8Mb.

Now, I have a computer with 64Gb of RAM and wanted to use some 50Gb for Cassandra. But now I'm wondering whether the extra 18Gb will really help or will it be filled up with many *useless* pointer data.

So my question is:

Does Cassandra manages a ton of small objects, or does it instead manage only a few large objects? (i.e. Does it allocate a separate buffer for each cell, each row, one buffer per sstable?)

In the first case, we may not gain much when going over 32Gb of Cassandra cache vs 50Gb.

Comment: it depends **massively** on data model and read/write load. 32gb should be sufficient for most loads.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink, we have one larger column, a document with about 4,000 words on average, we have maybe 20 other fields which are small numbers/dates/1 word, stuff like that. Now Mandraenke's answer gives me a tool to check out the heap so I'll be able to check my own heap and see how it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what one of my cluster nodes looks like from heap perspective:

```
# /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/jmap -histo -F 2480
Attaching to process ID 2480, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.121-b13
Iterating over heap. This may take a while...
Object Histogram:

num       #instances    #bytes  Class description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1:              1300610 1008416856      byte[]
2:              8451955 405693840       java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
3:              2349359 75179488        org.apache.cassandra.db.BufferCell
4:              2723073 73455464        java.nio.ByteBuffer[]
5:              1804559 57745888        org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.CompoundSparseCellName
6:              510867  46169960        java.lang.Object[]
7:              989235  23741640        java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Node
8:              25068   20455288        double[]
9:              851046  20425104        org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.CompoundDenseCellName
10:             580063  18562016        com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Node
11:             580056  18561792        com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentHashMapV8$Node
12:             42317   15771032        long[]
13:             600999  14423976        com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$WeightedValue
14:             590310  14167440        org.apache.cassandra.cache.KeyCacheKey
15:             554649  13311576        org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry
16:             35239   12545512        int[]
17:             434971  10439304        java.lang.Long
18:             143327  9172928 java.nio.DirectByteBufferR
19:             354204  8500896 java.lang.String
20:             98616   8241104 char[]
21:             37512   8102592 com.codahale.metrics.WeightedSnapshot$WeightedSample[]
22:             181096  7243840 org.apache.cassandra.db.BufferExpiringCell
23:             284486  6827664 org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicBTreeColumns$Holder
24:             264728  6353472 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.ColumnIdentifier
25:             264405  6345720 java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Index
26:             122067  4882680 org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexHelper$IndexInfo
27:             1       4194320 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentHashMapV8$Node[]
28:             99838   2396112 org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$LongToken
29:             89034   2136816 org.apache.cassandra.db.BufferDecoratedKey
30:             88888   2133312 org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicBTreeColumns
31:             64001   2048032 org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.CompoundSparseCellName$WithCollection
32:             58297   1399128 java.util.ArrayList
33:             56381   1353144 java.util.EnumMap$EntryIterator$Entry
34:             26794   1286112 java.util.HashMap
35:             37450   1198400 java.util.HashMap$Node
36:             47639   1143336 java.lang.Double
37:             35632   1140224 com.codahale.metrics.WeightedSnapshot$WeightedSample
38:             24311   972440  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
39:             18219   874512  org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.SSTableNamesIterator
40:             35651   855624  org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.BoundedComposite
41:             35610   854640  org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.CompoundComposite
42:             26165   837280  java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator
43:             1248    818688  io.netty.util.internal.shaded.org.jctools.queues.MpscArrayQueue
44:             25419   813408  org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry$IndexedEntry
45:             50021   800336  java.lang.Integer
46:             6585    736576  java.lang.Class
47:             4182    736032  org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService$Verb[]
48:             7718    652400  java.util.HashMap$Node[]
49:             19391   620512  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
50:             9349    600624  java.util.Hashtable$Entry[]
51:             12504   600192  java.util.TimSort
52:             18661   597152  java.util.Vector
53:             4100    557600  com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$PaddedAtomicReference
54:             4953    554736  java.net.SocksSocketImpl
55:             13215   528656  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$Index[]
56:             15888   508416  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$HeadIndex
57:             19379   465096  org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns$4
58:             9339    448272  java.util.Hashtable
59:             4520    419824  short[]
60:             25970   415520  java.lang.Object
61:             16148   387552  javax.management.ObjectName$Property
62:             9358    374320  java.security.ProtectionDomain
63:             12504   300096  com.codahale.metrics.WeightedSnapshot
64:             9356    299392  java.security.CodeSource
65:             12367   296808  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque$Node
66:             5891    282768  org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageOut
67:             5676    272448  java.util.TreeMap
68:             8542    271256  javax.management.ObjectName$Property[]
69:             8034    257088  java.util.EnumMap$EntryIterator
70:             7077    226464  java.net.InetAddress$InetAddressHolder
71:             7072    226304  java.util.ArrayList$Itr
72:             5644    225760  org.apache.cassandra.db.PreHashedDecoratedKey
73:             9288    222912  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node
74:             3085    222120  com.sun.jmx.remote.util.OrderClassLoaders
75:             3085    222120  javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$CombinedClassLoader
76:             3085    222120  javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$CombinedClassLoader$ClassLoaderWrapper
77:             6730    215360  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node
78:             8413    201912  org.apache.cassandra.db.DeletionInfo
79:             12504   200064  com.codahale.metrics.WeightedSnapshot$1
80:             4096    196608  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$TreeNode
81:             250     196544  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
82:             4881    195240  org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns
83:             4800    192000  java.util.ArrayList$SubList
84:             150     191840  io.netty.buffer.PoolSubpage[]
85:             3952    189696  org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask
86:             7635    183240  org.apache.thrift.protocol.TField
87:             3716    178368  org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceByNamesReadCommand
88:             2778    177792  io.netty.buffer.PoolSubpage
89:             1979    174152  java.lang.reflect.Method
90:             4271    170840  javax.management.ObjectName
91:             3522    169056  org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor
92:             2340    168480  org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol
93:             2990    167240  org.apache.cassandra.db.Cell[]
94:             5076    162432  org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns$ForwardsCellIterator
95:             425     159800  java.lang.Thread
96:             3988    159520  com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap
97:             4949    158368  java.net.Socket
98:             6548    157152  java.net.Inet4Address
99:             4870    155840  sun.misc.FDBigInteger
100:            9730    155680  java.util.HashSet
[...]
2865:           1       16      org.apache.cassandra.service.PendingRangeCalculatorService$1
2866:           1       16      sun.reflect.generics.tree.VoidDescriptor
2867:           1       16      org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$insert
Total :         25759325        -Xms7967M -Xmx7967M -Xmn800M
Heap traversal took 1130.769 seconds.
```

There are 25.759.325 instances on the heap and this node is started with `-Xms7967M -Xmx7967M -Xmn800M` - so there are quite a bunch of instances here.

For tuning resources see also: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

In one of my tests I ended up with running 4 Cassandra instances on a single host with 8GB heap each (on a machine with 64GB RAM, leaving 32 GB for OS page cache, with rack-awareness per host to be sure not losing more than one replica when a host comes down).

Comment: Excellent. I'm not very good with Java, I had no clue there was a tool to check the heap of a running process. This is great. I'll test our own instance that way too.

Comment: Question: Would you ever use more than one Cassandra instance on a single computer in production? It sounds somewhat dangerous to me to do that. Whenever you turn off the computer, all 4 nodes would go at the same time...